# Edit functionality for the link - UI

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, xampp

I have an image , on click of the image, it directs to a particular link , say "Google.com" as of now

The code as of now is as follows :

```
  <div class = "gallery">
        <ul>
           <li>
             <a target = "_blank " href="www.google.com"> <p>Google</p> <img src="images/1.jpg" alt ="" > </a>
           </li> 
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Now , I wanted to an edit functionality below the images. When I click on the edit button or symbol , it should give me the option to update the href location where the page should head to. 
For example : If I click on edit option, I should be able to change the href from Google.com to yahoo.com if needed... And when I click on the image next time, it should direct me to the updated link .

Any solutions or help would be really appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check demo :

https://jsfiddle.net/077vc41d/1/

```
<input id="urlInput" type="text" value ="http://www.google.com"/>
<button id="editButton">Edit</button>
<div class = "gallery">
    <ul>
       <li>
         <a id="linkTag" target = "_blank " href="http://www.google.com"> <p>Google</p> <img src="https://0.s3.envato.com/files/148768949/Prev%20big.png" alt ="" > </a>
       </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 document.getElementById("editButton").addEventListener("click",changeURL);
 function changeURL(e){
 var input = document.getElementById("urlInput");
 var link = document.getElementById("linkTag");
 linkTag.setAttribute("href",input.value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I was looking for !!

Comment: Ya just one more query: This Works great. But what if I don't want to see text box , and just want to see edit button... and on click of edit button, text box asking for new URL shud appear ?  Because I would have multiple images in a row and having so many text boxes visible might not look good .. Any suggestions ?

Comment: That was exactly what I asked ! Thanks a lot !! Cheers !

Comment: I have one clarification to ask: Since we use JavaScript, we might add edit feature .. and it works fine.. However, if I close the webpage and then open again, the one which we edited wouldn't be saved right ? It would have gone back to original link ?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a target="_blank " id="new" href="http://www.google.com">
        <p>Google</p> <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt=""> </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
Change URL<input type="text" id="newURL">
<button onclick="update()">Change</button>
```

JS:

```
function update() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newURL").value;
  document.getElementById("new").href = x;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/akqxWE

Comment: This Works great too ! Appreciate ur help !!

Comment: Thanks topjay :) .. if my post helped your question, please mark it as answered :)